# Coldfusion checkboxes same name

Tags: coldfusion

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ciccio" value="214124,qqqqq" />1
    <input type="checkbox" name="ciccio" value="675656,fggggggggg" />2
    <input type="checkbox" name="ciccio" value="125676,gfsdsasssss" />3
    <input type="checkbox" name="ciccio" value="898797,looooooo" />4
    <input type="submit" value="vai" />
</form>
```

I need to insert in database the value of "form.ciccio". When I dump that variable the result is:

```
Ciccio: 214124,qqqqq,675656,fggggggggg,125676,gfsdsasssss,898797,looooooo
```

I have tried using:

```
<cfset testing = form["ciccio[]"]>
```

But it is not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Check box values get passed as a comma separated list so if your value contain csv data you either have to process 2 values at a time or use another delimiter  other  than comma.

```
<input name="c" type="checkbox" value="12345|lolololol">
```

Then loop over the list and pull out the sub data with `ListFirst()` and `ListRest()`

Answer (score 5):

For CF10+, use `this.sameformfieldsasarray=true;` in Application.cfc

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/19/ColdFusion-10-Missing-Feature-Form-Fields-and-Arrays

Comment: That's awesome, didn't know about that change in CF 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert in database value of "form.ciccio" 
comma is default delimiter.

```
    <cfloop index="i" list=#form.ciccio# > 

      <cfif condition >
         insert int value
      <cfelse>
         insert text value
      </cfif>

    </cfloop>
```